# Getting "Undefined is not a function" error when using the Revealing Prototype Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, revealing-prototype

I'm trying to employ the Revealing Prototype Pattern in a JavaScript file to encapsulate two collections of related functions.  But when the page loads, it returns the following error at the call to the .init function:

"Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function."

Here is the pattern for my markup.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        testProto1.init();
        testProto2.init();
    });
</script>
```

And here is the pattern in my JavaScript file.

```
var testProto1 = function () {

};

testProto1.prototype = function () {
    var init = function () {
        alert("init 1");
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }
}();


var testProto2 = function () {

};

testProto2.prototype = function () {
    var init = function () {
        alert("init 2");
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }
}();
```

This is probably some basic syntax error on my part, and I do apologize if it's a duplicate.  Why am I seeing this error and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.  This code looks messed up in a whole bunch of different ways, but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do so don't know what to suggest.  `testProto1.init()` doesn't work because there's no `.init()` property on the `testProto1` constructor function.

Comment: @jfriend00, My intent is to namespace the functions that I'm using. One set of functions manipulates a grid, and the other handles math calculations. Rather than mixing the various functions, this pattern helps encapsulate the functions under logical units.

Comment: If you just want to namespace some functions that are not actually methods of an instantiated object, then you don't use the prototype at all.  You just put properties on an object and call those properties.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You're right. I may investigate further down the road, but at this point the code is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the concepts of prototypes & function instances incorrectly in a lot of ways.

You need to `instantiate` a function with the `new` operator if you want to be able to access prototypes.

From what it looks like you're trying to achieve this:

```
var testProto1 = function () { };

// Create your methods in object notation within your prototype
testProto1.prototype.init = function () { 
    alert('init called');
};
```

Now if you want to call this, you have to `instantiate` it!

```
var proto1 = new testProto1();

// NOW you can call .init! Because the prototype was actually created

proto1.init(); // alerts 'init called!'
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I had used this pattern a long time ago at another company, and no longer had that code. That's exactly where my problem was.

Comment: Not a problem, best of luck! @KenPalmer

Answer (score 1):

you can access prototype's properties from instances of this Object, so this will work:

```
var a=new testProto1();
a.init();
```

if you want to acces init function from testProto1 you must write:

```
testProto1.prototype.init();
```

so your code will look like:

```
    $(function () {
    testProto1.prototype.init();
    testProto2.prototype.init();
});
```